# what is the real meaning of #10 verilog testbench?

Tags: verilog

I am new in verilog programming. So I was trying to explore the meaning of simple MUX code. In the test bench, It is observed there are multiple " #10 "s.
what is the purpose of this line?

Also please explain the need of defining inputs as "reg" and output simply as "wires"

I have added the snapshot for reference.

[image: TB Image]
Thanks in advance.

Vt

Comment: It simply implies: After 10 units of delay, execute the trailing statements.

Comment: See http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg for the difference between wires and reg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does #\`DEL mean in verilog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793079/what-does-del-mean-in-verilog)

Comment: The use of a define is helpful in documenting delays, instead of fixed number.  The syntax of ``#`DELAY`` or better ``#(`CLOCK*10)`` can be used to denote time period in simulation.  Also, this should not be used in synthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds `10 units of time delay` before executing the statement.

```
@always(clock.posedge) begin
    #10
    c = a + b
end
```

The above example adds a and b after `10 units of delay` from `posedge of clock`

Answer (score 0):

> #10 determines the time delay before the operation.

"reg" and "wire" are data types ,to know the detail difference between different data types refer :

> Verilog HDL: A Guide to Digital Design and Synthesis
>   By Samir Palnitkar